# black/blank screen iOS simulator on VMware

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, macos-catalina

I am having a weird issue with simulator it shows me this screen

I have searched around for a solution and have tried to reset the content and settings it didn't work

[image: Screen Shot]

Currently, I have Xcode version 11.3 (11C29) and macOS version 10.15 beta installed. When I run the project with iPhone 11 pro 13.3 it shows me the black screen.

Unlike regular/ initial ios simulator set up, there are no apps installed by default.

I am running mac on VMware. Any kind of help is really helpful.

Comment: Installing macOS Catalina 10.15.2 with Xcode 11.3.1 solved the issue on VMware

Comment: I have the same problem. Where did you download 10.15.2  vmdk file?

Comment: I followed this video to install a new machine on VM from scratch. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gr2fQXgcb2U&t=688s

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally I could solve it.

Comment: awesome please give my question upvote so people know it worked :)

Comment: @Aforandroid is Xcode iOS simulator working fine with macOS Catalina 10.15.2 with Xcode 11.3.1 ?

Comment: @Dzilva the last time I used xcode it was working fine

Comment: @Aforandroid thanks mate! still it's working fine (almost). I just tested yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue, got it fixed by using the correct version of Xcode

For VMWare Catalina - 10.15 Beta(197a471t) use Xcode - 10.3

Use this site to Download Specefic Xcode from Apple -> https://xcodereleases.com

It also fixed a Assets.Xcassets problem I was facing (LaunchImage Problem), really bad the MacOS is so specific with these versions
Hope you get it fixed...

P.S for virtual Box users there is a command line fix ->https://wasaytechtips.com/springboard-quit-unexpectedly/